# Defaulting MySite Email Notifications to off?

Tags: 2010, my-site, email

On the SharePoint 2010 MySite EditProfile.aspx, there are settings for Email Notifications:

```
[x] Notify me when someone leaves a note on my profile.
[x] Notify me when someone adds me as a colleague.
[x] Send me suggestions for new colleagues and keywords.

Select which e-mail notifications you want to receive.
```

Unfortunately, they default to having all three options checked. I would like to set different defaults for all users, present and future and have them explicitly Opt in to these.

Is there any way to do that? The idea of just executing a SQL UPDATE to set Property 5040 to 7 fails because that property doesn't exist by default in the database, and if SharePoint can't find it in the database it defaults to 0 (=all checked).

Answer (score 3):

You should NEVER execute any SQL directly for production SharePoint databases (except the reporting database). You should use PowerShell or the Object Model.

There is no way to set the default that I can see.

You can loop through the existing profiles and look for the "SPS-EmailOptin" property. Then set it to 7. The challenge is to determine the profiles where the end user has already indicated that they wish to receive all notifications ("0"). Something like:

```
$up = $upm.GetUserProfile("DHT\Willa")
$up["SPS-EmailOptin"].Value = 7
$up.Commit()
```

You can also address this with training, let the user get the notification and opt out my clicking the Edit Profile link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

http://vallery.net/2011/01/13/disable-email-notifications-in-sharepoint-2010/

It works perfectly. But if we want to enable it back we need to set the

$oUser["SPS-EmailOptin"].Value =0;

For new users how can i disable this option as it comes by default.

Any help in modifying the power shell script in the above link is highly appreciated

Thanks,
Sandy